# Why submitHandler is not working on mobile?

Tags: microsoft-teams

We've implemented this code in the tab on our app:

```
microsoftTeams.tasks.startTask(
    taskInfo: TaskInfo,
    submitHandler?: (err: string, result: string | any) => void
): void;

microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(
    result?: string | any,
    appIds?: string | string[]
): void;
```

It works fine on the web app, but it doesn't work on the mobile app, the `submitHandler` callback is never called.

Please advice.
Thank you,

Comment: We referred this sample(https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-task-module) and its working fine at our end in Mobile devices. Could you please check at your end and let us know if that helps?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I've found the issue and a workaround. Looks like submitTask doesn't support a big result object / string. I was passing a big object, now that I've removed it, it works pretty well.

Comment: But weird that the same code works on desktop but does not work on mobile..